# django rest related records serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently developing a school system using django rest. I have a tables for subjects, students and table subject attendance connecting subjects and students. There is also table grade which collect all the grades and is connected with subject attendance.

I would like to make an API request like this:
api/subjects?student=1
To see all the subjects of that student. This is easy using filtering. But how to display only the grades of that student not all of the given subject grades? Serialize relation will give my all the grades...

I have this models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher, through='SubjectManagement', related_name='subjects')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='SubjectAttendance', related_name='subjects')
    ...
    def getStudentGrades(self,id):
        now = datetime.datetime.now
        gs = Grade.objects.filter(subjectAttendance__student__id = id, subjectAttendance__start__lte=now,
                             subjectAttendance__end__gte=now)
        return json.dumps(gs)


class SubjectAttendance(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

class Grade(models.Model):
    subjectAttendance = models.ForeignKey(SubjectAttendance)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return json.dumps(self)
```

I also have now simple serializer:

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    grades = serializers.Field(source='getStudentGrades')

    class Meta:
        model = Subject
```

Regards,
jan

Comment: Could you post the code you already have?

Comment: what's your problem now! the model method sounds fine

Comment: I know I can use a model method in serializer like I did (getStudentGrades) but the question is: can I pass somehow the student id from url (/api/subjects?student=1) into that method? Or there is other method to filter which grades connected to particular subject are shown?

Comment: You could create a custom action for a ViewSet that would take the ID as a parameter and would then pass it to the serializer.

Comment: You do not get access to the `Request` object in either of the ways to use a method (models or serialisers). Use a viewset. In a viewset, `self.request` is the `Request` object.

Also See documentation on relationships http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations